# the robust way to combine multiple dataframe considering different input scenarios

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There are three data frames, `df_1, df_2 and df_3`.  I combined them as follows

```
result1 = df_1.append(df_2,ignore_index=True)   
result2 = result1.append(df_3,ignore_index=True)
```

Then `result2` is the combined `dataframe`. This code segment current works fine if neither of these three input data frames is empty.
However, in practice, any of these three input data frames can be empty. What is the most efficient approach to handle these different scenarios without implementing complex if-else logic to evaluate different scenarios, e.g., df_1 is empty, or both `df_1` and `df_3` are empty, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with list of Dataframes, it working if all or any DataFrame(s) are empty:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame()
df_2 = pd.DataFrame()
df_3 = pd.DataFrame()

df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2, df_3],ignore_index=True)
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

---

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame()
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2]})
df_3 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[10,20]})

df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2, df_3],ignore_index=True)
print (df)
    a
0   1
1   2
2  10
3  20
```

---

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame()
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2]})
df_3 = pd.DataFrame()

df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2, df_3],ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   a
0  1
1  2
```